# Android Bitmap becomes null in previously working code

Tags: android, android-bitmap, mediastore

Four years ago I started developing an app that allows the user to pick images, and then the app animates the images. I did the work in Eclipse and I am 100% SURE that the app worked.

Fast forward to 2018, I still have the old source code, and I want to improve it. I imported it into Android Studio and it still builds and runs.

However, something must have changed with how Android works since then, because the images now become empty.

In debug, I find that `selectedImagePath` is calculated, it's not null, so therefore I assume it's correct.

One example when running in the emulator:`/document/primary:Download/x.gif` (and of course that image exists).

One example when running on a phone: `/document/image:2375` (confusingly, it's actually called `x.png` and resides in the standard Download folder).

Still, `bitmap` is always null. Any ideas?

```
Uri selectedImageUri;
selectedImageUri = data.getData();
selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String selectedImagePath;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }else{
        selectedImagePath = null;
    }

    if(selectedImagePath == null){
        //2:OI FILE Manager --- call method: uri.getPath()
        selectedImagePath = uri.getPath();
    }
    return selectedImagePath;
}
```

Comment: pick from a custom file manager instead of default document picker.. see if it helps

Comment: I think the problem is on Runtime Permission which introduced from Android 6.0. You may verify this by using emulator with Android 4.4 or 5.0.

Comment: `/document/primary:Download/x.gif` and  `/document/image:2375` are no file system paths. So it makes no sense trying to use them for file actions.

Comment: You can do away with getPath() and load the bitmap from the uri directly. Much less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
```

Change to

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Dare I asked why my code worked 4 years ago and today doesn't? I have tested your solution on two different phones and the solution works on both. (Some weirdness, like on the older phone there's sometimes a reasonable warning log that the selected image is too large and 50% of the time it then doesn't work, but in 50% it still works anyway.)

Comment: I discovered a more subtle issue. As long as I am running the app, it has permission to read the selected image. I store the Uri persistently. When I restart the app, it gets the old Uri inside `onCreate()` and tries to get the bitmap again, and now throws Exception: `Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`.

Comment: Yes. Pretty normal.

Comment: Really? That's a bit scary. :) Why does it require `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` twice, and why doesn't it find that I already set that in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and finally, why does that work on my API17 phone but not on my API24 phone?

Comment: Please edit your post. Start with the used intent as i dont know what you are doing. Then a decent onActivityResult(). After that we can come to the point.

Comment: I created a new post since the discussion is getting a bit off topic here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604552/android-issues-reading-images-from-persistent-uri

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that your uri not start from file://

```
private String getImagePathFromUri(Uri imageUri) {
    if (imageUri != null) {
        if (imageUri.toString().startsWith("file://")) {
            return imageUri.getEncodedPath();
        } else {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String imageEncoded = null;
                    try {
                        imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return imageEncoded;
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```