# Android issues reading images from persistent Uri

Tags: android, persistence, android-permissions, backwards-compatibility

My app lets the user select images and then it animates the images. It's a simple thing and I want it to run on 4.2 and onwards. It works perfectly now.

The app is supposed to remember the chosen images and let these be default the next time the user runs the app - when the app is restarted.

This works beautifully on my Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1) but not so well on my Galaxy S8+ (7.0). Since I love how it works on 4.2.1, it's a bit frustrating that it can't simply run the same on later platforms.

This is inside `onCreate()`:

```
((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagex))
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select image"), SELECT_IMAGEX);
        }
    });
```

From `onActivityResult`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    // [snip unimportant code] 
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(uri);

    final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.w(myLog, "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    // [snip]
    editor.putString("imagex", uri.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Later, the app is restarted and this part of the method `onCreate()` goes:

```
String tmp = preferences.getString("imagex", null);
if (tmp != null) {
    uri = Uri.parse(tmp);
    Bitmap bitmap  = getBitmap(uri);
    // etc
}
```

On the S8+, getBitmap() gives an exception `Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` (meaning the method returns null).

It's quite confusing why it would complain about one single missing permission TWICE in one single exception message. By the way, it still does so after adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />`.

Reading on this great site, I find people talking about

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
           & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
           | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(selectedImageUri, takeFlags);
```

which is some fairly modern invention, but unfortunately it just causes this on the S8+

```
SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found
```

and on the Galaxy Nexus it simply crashes by

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

Comment: Please start your post with the code for the intent you use. I asked you before to show your intent code as otherwise we dont know what you are doing. Most things depend on the used intent.

Comment: Thanks. I've added more details above.

Comment: Using ACTION_GET_CONTENT you cannot take persistable permissions as they are not offered you. For persistable permissions you have to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Inspect for both which bits/flags in getFlags() are set and you will see.

Comment: Progress! The app as before has getFlags() = `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`
and if I change to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead getFlags() = `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FILL_IN_SELECTOR`. I don't understand that, but it did make a difference. It now runs without exception on the newer phone but on the older phone which worked before I now cannot select image.

Comment: Typo above, should of course be getFlags() = `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
 | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FILL_IN_SELECTOR`

Comment: As an experiment I commented out the line with `takePersistableUriPermission()` and it still works on the newer phone. (I didn't expect that!)

Comment: No it is not FILL_IN_SELECTOR. That flag has a different name. You miss the point now as the flag indicates that you are offered a persistable permission. (Sorry forgot the name).

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT gives FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_UR_PERMISSION.

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT gives only FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.

Comment: So only if you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT you can take a persistable uri permission. Which will give you access to the choosen file also after closing your app and restart.

Comment: I dont know what your app is doing. You are not even telling which of the two you use. And when. And how.

Comment: `I think the return value was 0x43 ` What should i do with that info? What are you trying to say? Which return value? From what ? When? How?

Comment: My god... should i know wich bits/flags are set with that value? You could put some effort in explaining the bits/flags. What is it that i did for you then!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Let me try again. 0x43 is 64+2+1. FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION = 64 according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html so you were correct and I quoted the wrong constant FILL_IN_SELECTOR which is also 64.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` issues in the following way, using the very helpful comment section above.

Inside onCreate():

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
else
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

Inside onActivityResult():

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(myLog, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

For Android API24, my newer phone, it works for all images that I've tried so far, both those in the Downloads directory, and those from the camera gallery.

**HOWEVER**:

For Android API17, my older phone, while it does work for images in Downloads, I discover that I get the following exception for some other images on the phone during `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.gallery3d.provider.GalleryProvider from ProcessRecord ... 
requires com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER or 
com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER
```